# При создании таблицы в значение по умолчанию указать кириллическую строку

Tags: mysql

Есть файл в кодировке utf-8, в нём описана структура базы данных. Кодировка базы данных utf-8. Для поля таблицы есть следующее определение

```
title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Нет заголовка'
```

Структуру создаю через консоль посредством запроса

```
source "путь к файлу"
```

В итоге при создании записи без указания поля **title** получаем каракули. На каракули смотрю через phpmyadmin, поэтому кодировка консоли не причём.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение. Для этого в начало своего файла структуры БД я добавил.

```
SET NAMES 'utf8';
```

Каракули получается из за того, что по умолчанию при подключение к mysql серверу он ставит кодировку **latin1**, таким образом указанное DEFAULT значение искажается и в дальнейшем может попадать в базу данных. Еще возможное решение это изменения настроек mysql сервера, в частности кодировки по умолчанию при подключении.